# How to have a delay in seconds on timer app?

Tags: swift, timer, nstimer

I am attempting to create a time app that is for the time that is a little off, such as I want a second in the app that is actually 1.5 seconds in real time. Currently, I am running into errors on changing the time label and have no idea where to start on adjusting the time I want compared to real time.

```
func updateCounter() {
   timeLabel.text = String(counter+=1)
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var timer = Timer()
    var counter = 0
    timeLabel.text = String(counter)
}
```

I am receiving the following error.

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(())'

Any help would be great.

Comment: How are triggering `updateCounter()`?  Also `var counter` is not available to `updateCounter()` because it is inside `viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var aTimer: Timer!
let defaultTimeInterval = 1.5
var counter = 0.0
var adjustedCounter = 0.0
let timeLabel = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    aTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: defaultTimeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateCounter() {
    counter += defaultTimeInterval
    adjustedCounter += 1
    let displayText = "original: \(counter)  adjusted: \(adjustedCounter)"
    timeLabel.text = displayText
    print(displayText)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the variable `counter` global and increment the counter in a separate line inside of `updateCounter()`:

```
var counter = 0

func  {
   counter += 1
   timeLabel.text = String(counter)
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
   super.viewDidLoad()
    var timer = Timer()
    timeLabel.text = String(counter)
}
```

`counter+=1` does not return a value, and that's why you can't pass as an argument to the String initializer.